# displaying images from sql database with classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

i am creating a home page and have a news section. currently the news section displays the top 3 news titles/headlines from the database they are stored in. How the owner wants it now is that an image should be displayed next to the news headline relating to that news article. So i have set up a function where by they upload an image into the news database against the article they have just created/uploaded into the database, now all i want to do is display this image that is saved in the database. Is there a way to do this?

i am using classic asp and html/javascript.

so far the code i have is:

```
<img id="news_image2" alt="<%=rsNews("Image_Name")%>" border="0" height="70" name="Image" src="<%=rsNews("news_Image")%>" title="Echo_Images" width="80" align="middle" /> </a>
```

Many thanks

EDIT. tHE IS THE rsnews on homepage.asp

```
    <%@  language="VBSCRIPT" codepage="1252" %>
    <!-- #include file="Connections/echo.asp" -->
<%
Dim rsNews
Dim rsNews_numRows

Set rsNews = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsNews.ActiveConnection = MM_echo_STRING
rsNews.Source = "SELECT top 3 News_Article_ID,News_Article_Create_Date,News_Txt_Date,News_Title,News_Publish_Date,News_Expiry_Date,News_Title_Header,News_Active,Admin_ID,News_Ticker,display,Image_Name,displayCode,news_Image FROM tblNews WHERE News_Active = 1 AND News_Expiry_Date >= getDate() AND (display = 'ext' OR display = 'both'OR displayCode=1 OR displayCode=4 OR displayCode=5 OR displayCode=7) ORDER BY News_TXT_Date DESC"
rsNews.CursorType = 0
rsNews.CursorLocation = 2
rsNews.LockType = 1
 rsNews.Open()

rsNews_numRows = 0
%>
<div id="news-home-container">

                         <!--news item 1-->
                        <div>
                           <div class="news-home-image">
                                    <a href="about/echo_news.aspx?id=0">
                                        <img id="news_image2" alt="LatestNews" border="0" height="70" name="logo_link0" src="image_display.asp?PhotoID=627" title="Echo_Images" width="80" align="middle" /></a> </div>

                            <div class="newsDiv">
                          <a href="about/echo_news.aspx?id=0" ><b style="line-height:1.3em"><%=rsNews("News_Title")%></b>
                  <p><%=rsNews("News_Title_Header")%></p></a>                                                                        
                     </div>
                            </div>
                         <!--End of news item 1-->
```

now i need the images that are saved to the top 3 articles in the database to be displayed .

this is the code in image_display.asp

```
    <!-- #include file="Connections/echo.asp" -->

<%
    Dim sql
    Dim rs
    Dim conn
    Dim userID,str

   userID = Request("PhotoId")
   If userID = "" Then userID = 0

   'Instantiate Objects
   Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

   'Open connection
```

' rsNews.ActiveConnection = MM_echo_STRING
   'conn = uncomment this line and insert your connection string here
       'Get the specific image based on the ID passed in a querystring
       str = "SELECT news_Image FROM tblNews WHERE news_article_id =" & userID
        rs.Open str, conn,3,3
        if rs.eof then 'No records found
            Response.End
        else 'Display the contents
            Response.ContentType = "image/gif" 
            Response.BinaryWrite(rs("news_Image")) 
       end if

```
   'destroy the variables.
   rs.Close
    conn.Close
   set rs = Nothing
   set conn = Nothing
 %>
```

Comment: MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle? Are you storing a path to the image in the database? or the binary (blob) of the image itself?

Comment: HeavenCore is is MS SQL and it is being stored as binary

Comment: are you storing it in a varbinary or image type column?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

heavencore's answer is right 
you just need to check if you are binary writing hte right thing
so check if you are passing the right id onto the page and then where it says response.binarywrite rs("ImageBlob")  - imageblob is the field where you saved your image as binary data

Edit after seeing your comment:

I have just had a look in your source code -

you where this line of code is

```
<img id="news_image2" alt="LatestNews" border="0" height="70" name="logo_link0"      src="images/News_images/default image.jpg" title="Echo_Images" width="80" align="middle" />
```

You need to replace it with -

```
<img id="news_image2" alt="LatestNews" border="0" height="70" name="logo_link0" src="somefile.asp?ID=2" title="Echo_Images" width="80" align="middle" />
```

so you just change the src="" to src="somefile.asp?id=2"

and then in somefile.asp you put this code -

```
Dim ImageID
ImageID = request.querystring("ID")
Set rs = db.Execute("SELECT ImageBlob FROM table WHERE ID = " & ImageID)

Response.Expires = 0 
Response.Buffer = TRUE 
Response.Clear 
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg" '#### Assuming your images are jpegs
Response.BinaryWrite rs("ImageBlob")
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi the issue i have is that the images will be displayed on a home page, so there will be no querystring at the top of the page

Comment: please see the website www.echo-ms.com and the thumbnails at the bottown of the screen (that say echo) need to be altered to images relating to that news article from the database

Comment: can you post your code? I will have a look  - or any errors you getting?

Comment: Ok i just had a look in your code - what do you see when you excite this link - http://www.echo-ms.com/<yourdirectory>/image_display.asp?PhotoID=627 - replace <yourdirectory> with your website folder - let me know if there is an error here if this works then they will display in your homepage also try a jpeg instead of gif too

Comment: the error i get is
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 

Object required: 'rsNews' 

/image_display.asp, line 18

Comment: look for  'conn = uncomment this line and insert your connection string here in your code and put in your connection string  - you are not deifining a connection string and I have commented a rsnew line. check edit above and then execute that link again and let me know the error

Comment: i have rejigged it and now gettin this C:\Users\reidkz\Pictures\abstract-green-background-2560x1600.jpg
which is where the image was stored

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - what is this -  C:\Users\reidkz\Pictures\abstract-green-background-2560x1600.jpg  ? Also did you approve my edit to see the changes i made?

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out. the issue was that the image was not been loaded into the database correctly so i recreated the page where the image was loaded and then used Jatins code above, only altering the "ID" to "News_Article_ID". once this was done i entered the following code into the img source

```
img src="Image_Display.asp?news_Article_iD=<%=rsnews("News_article_id")%>"
```

many thaks for your help everyone

Answer (score -1):

Ok, based on your comments you'll need to create a new asp page, lets call it getImage.asp.

You would reference the image in your HTML as follows:

```
<img src="getImage.asp?ID=<%=rsNews("Image_ID") %>">
```

where getImage.asp is something like this (note the use of response.BinaryWrite:

```
Dim ImageID
ImageID = request.querystring("ID")
Set rs = db.Execute("SELECT ImageBlob FROM table WHERE ID = " & ImageID)

Response.Expires = 0 
Response.Buffer = TRUE 
Response.Clear 
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg" '#### Assuming your images are jpegs
Response.BinaryWrite rs("ImageBlob")
```

Comment: ok im goin to give this a go and ill let you know how i get on